# ‘QRootElement.h file not found’ error when building an Xcode project that uses QuickDialog

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I would like to use [QuickDialog](https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog) but I can't use it without errors.

Here's what I did:

1. Drag the .xcodeproj project in to my Xcode 4 project. The default options 'Create groups for any added folders' and 'Add to targets' was selected
2. Selected my project from the Xcode sidebar and then the target I want to add QuickDialog to.
3. Selected the Build Phases tab.
4. Under the Target Dependencies group, clicked the plus button, select the QuickDialog static library target.
5. Under the Link Binary Libraries group, clicked the plus button, select libQuickDialog.a.
6. Added "$(SOURCE_ROOT)/Build" to the target's Header Search path.
7. Added "-ObjC" in Other Linker Flag

Now, if I build (cmd + b) everything works! But if in my own code, I add, for instance:

```
#import "QRootElement.h"
```

I get a lot of errors:

```
'QRootElement.h' file not found
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
error: unable to open executable '/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SaGASForm-gvoiwjscornqdcfjxbxtdjcwxnwq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectForm.app/ProjectForm'
```

My project has been set to use ARC with LLVM 3.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your XCode project can't find the header files in the subproject.

in step 6, you're probably not linking to the proper directory with the header files.

There are detailed information on how to add QuickDialog to your project here: http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog